# AWS SDK NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

Tags: android, amazon-s3, noclassdeffounderror, aws-sdk

I've been trying to upload a video I took to a bucket of S3 services using the AWS SDK.

this is the code that I took from the Amazon example for S3 uploading. The only things I'm doing differently is:

1. not creating a new bucket but reusing the one that is already there.
2. using a predetermined Uri for the file where the image is.

   ```
   public void uploadToS3(View v) {
       AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(
           Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY));
       String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(fileUri, filePathColumn,
           null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
       String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
       cursor.close();

       // Put the image data into S3.
       try {
           //s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());

           PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                   Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                   new java.io.File(filePath)); // Content type is determined
                                                // by file extension.
           s3Client.putObject(por);
       } catch (Exception exception) {
           // displayAlert( "Upload Failure", exception.getMessage() );
       }
   }
   ```

the problem is, once I try and create the `AmazonS3Client`, the app crashes with a `noClassFound` exception.

here is my Logcat:

```
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2154)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    ... 11 more
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at com.thepoosh.aws.s3upload.android.CameraToAmazonaws3Activity.uploadToS3(CameraToAmazonaws3Activity.java:63)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    ... 14 more
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.thepoosh.aws.s3upload.android-1.apk]
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-17 10:42:02.555: E/AndroidRuntime(20310):    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Maybe problem related to your resources such as main.xml

Comment: @omidnazifi, what do you mean? there is no xml for the `AWS SDK`

Comment: is your library in "libs" folder? And properly added to your project?

Comment: @MuratNafiz, I have no `libs` folder in my project. am I supposed to add it and put something in there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code gives `NoClassDefFoundError` because you didnt add the sdk's library to your project. Here is how you can do it

- Right click on your project name -> New -> Folder and name it "`libs`" (without `"`s)
- You should add `"aws-android-sdk-X.X.X-debug.jar"` in this library folder
- Right click on your project name -> Properties -> select Java Build Path from left -> Click Add Jars -> navigate to your projects `libs` which we created.
- select `"aws-android-sdk-X.X.X-debug.jar"`
- Click Ok and you are done.

Hope this helps

Comment: well, the only problem now is: i get an `unknownHost` error, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add the internet permission in your manifest file? You can do this by adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: OMG I'm such a newb :S how did I forget this?!?!?!

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem as well. But the Jar is 6MB! Can we just use s3 to upload pics?

Comment: public final class java.lang.Class implements java.io.Serializable, java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement, java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration, java.lang.reflect.Type