# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have imported the S3Uploader example in my eclipse (ADT eclipse) and i am trying to run it.

I have imported the proeject and then added following jars
Project > Properties > java build path > add jars

02/02/2014  01:24 PM         6,376,630 aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-debug.jar
02/02/2014  01:14 PM           281,550 aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-s3.jar
02/02/2014  01:24 PM         5,587,005 aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1.jar

project compiles and builds fine.But when i run it  it gives following exception

```
02-02 13:39:03.151: E/dalvikvm(20716): Could not find class 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client', referenced from method com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity.<init>
02-02 13:39:03.151: W/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 40 (Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client;) in Lcom/amazonaws/demo/s3uploader/S3UploaderActivity;
02-02 13:39:03.151: D/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0004
02-02 13:39:03.151: D/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0018 in Lcom/amazonaws/demo/s3uploader/S3UploaderActivity;.<init> ()V
02-02 13:39:03.161: W/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client;)
02-02 13:39:03.161: W/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: unable to resolve static field 33 (US_WEST_2) in Lcom/amazonaws/regions/Regions;
02-02 13:39:03.161: D/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0005
02-02 13:39:03.161: D/dalvikvm(20716): VFY: dead code 0x0007-003c in Lcom/amazonaws/demo/s3uploader/S3UploaderActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
02-02 13:39:03.161: D/AndroidRuntime(20716): Shutting down VM
02-02 13:39:03.161: W/dalvikvm(20716): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at com.amazonaws.demo.s3uploader.S3UploaderActivity.<init>(S3UploaderActivity.java:45)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1777)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
02-02 13:39:03.161: E/AndroidRuntime(20716):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have also looked at [AWS SDK NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631855/aws-sdk-noclassdeffounderror-com-amazonaws-services-s3-amazons3client)

and it also says to to what i have alredy done.

How do i fix it?

Comment: in your build path, in order and export, is the library checked?

Comment: When I tried ticking the Amazon libraries in 'Order and Export' my project does not run due to out of memory problems and I need to restart Eclipse...

Comment: ...I fixed that problem by following the steps here in order to increase the heap size available to Eclipse: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the errormyself using following:

Created a libs folder (libs not lib)And copied all jars to that folder.And it worked fine.
ADT automatially puts a build time dependency on the jars inside libs folder.And it worked fine.

Originally my jars were in lib folder and i have explicit dependecy on it.So it worked at compile time but these libs were not packaked inside APK.This was strange bu i also read this somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to follow the steps outlined in [our blog](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20QCGGQZLH23U/Running-AWS-SDK-for-Android-samples-in-Eclipse-with-ADT-v22) to export the libraries for use in an Android application.

Comment: This should be the correct answer - esp. as it includes a link to increasing the heap memory available to Eclipse: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F